# Excel JS API - copy and store EXACT range values, formats, and formulas in a json file to be used later to generate same range of values

Tags: office-js

With the office js api you can copy a range of cells to another range of cells and preserve everything from the values, formulas, and formats using code that looks something like this:

```
sheet.getRange(“A1”).copyFrom("M9:R424");
```

I want to duplicate this functionality but rather than store the values, formulas, and formats of the cells in the excel file, I’d like to store them in a json file (in a db outside the app) so that I can dynamically create sheets with the ranges/cells as needed to reduce the size of the excel file and to make sure that users don’t accidentally edit the template ranges.

So far I’ve been able to replicate the values and the formulas from the json but am having trouble with the formats. There’s a format object you can get from the range:

```
range.format
```

But when I convert this format to json using:

```
range.format.toJSON()
```

There’s a serious amount of parameters lacking (e.g. cell fill color, border outline).

Does anyone know a more optimal way to convert the range formats to json or to store and replicate this data?

Answer (score 1):

We have [RangeFill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangefill?view=excel-js-preview) and [RangeBorderCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangebordercollection?view=excel-js-preview) class, you could use `toJSON()` API to get the cell fill color and border color.

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {

    var range = context.workbook.getActiveCell();
    range.format.fill.load();
    range.format.borders.load();
    await context.sync();

    var JSON = range.format.fill.toJSON();
    var JSON2 = range.format.borders.toJSON();

    console.log(JSON);
    console.log(JSON2);

  });
```

Comment: I think this gets me going in the right direction so thanks for that. Can you post an example code snippet of using the toJSON() API? Whenever I use it, I'm getting an empty object so I'm obviously doing something wrong. Also, is there a way to get all these properties in one sweep rather than call them individually?

Thanks!

Comment: I will prepare one for you early of next week

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your time!

Comment: I just update the code sample.thanks for your reminder